# Create connected app using metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, connected-apps, package, remote-site-settings

I have created managed package that uses metadata API to create connected App. It is working fine in my developer org where I am creating package. When I install this package in different org, It is asking for remote site setting.

I added a method to create remote site setting, which is working fine in my developer org.when I add this method in package and install in different org, again that requires endpoint.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: To create remote site setting you need to add the endpoint of the org where you are creating the remote-site  setting

Comment: I believe metadata API requires endpoint of salesforce instance, so it should be a post package installation step.

Comment: @Ashwani I am trying to create remote site setting from VF page and getting error "Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://my-domain-name--khel.ap2.visual.force.com/services/Soap/m/38.0" . Do I need to create this  endpoint manually ?

Comment: @RahulSharma yes I am creating remote site setting and connected app through button on a VF page . After installing the package .

Comment: @AJAYPRAKASHDUBEY that endpoint must be added into the org before invoking the metadata api. Metadata API required callout.

Answer (score 1):

You may have performed callout not to a canonical URL but to Visualforce domain or some other domain. You can actually perform successfully self-callouts without any RemoteSiteSettings, but you need to get the correct Domain URL by calling `getBaseURL()` method

```
/**
 * Determines the true API hostname for a Salesforce org using the Identity API.
 * eg 'https://pod.salesforce.com' (most orgs)
 * eg 'https://custom.my.salesforce.com' (my domain)
 * eg 'https://custom--dev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com' (sandbox orgs)
 */
public static String getBaseURL() {
    String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();
    String userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    String sessionId = getLexSid();
    //use getSalesforceBaseUrl within batches and schedules (not Visualforce), and fix inconsistent protocol
    if (sessionId == null) {
        return Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().replace('http:', 'https:');
    }
    
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/id/' + orgId + '/' + userId);
    pr.getParameters().put('oauth_token', sessionId);
    pr.getParameters().put('format', 'json');
    
    //within test context use url class, else derive from identity api
    String data = Test.isRunningTest() ? '{"urls": {"rest": "' + Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '"}}' : pr.getContent().toString();
    Url rest = new Url(new Parser(data).readString('urls.rest').replace('{version}', '55'));
    return rest.getProtocol() + '://' + rest.getHost();
}
```

Once you know the correct domain (https://custom.my.salesforce.com or https://custom--dev.sandbox.my.salesforce.com), you may perform Metadata API calls to create Connected Apps or Remote Site Settings to different sites or Visualforce domain or Lightning domain.